# Migration from one giant Subversion repository to many small Git repos

Tags: git, git-svn

I’m working on a Git to Subversion migration. We have the following layout in one Subversion repository:

```
Common
|-- Module A
|-- Module B
|-- Module C
`-- Module D
```

We have a couple of different needs, and everything I’ve found so far hasn’t worked.

First, we’d like to migrate just one module, but also maintain the root folder. For example, I’d like to migrate Module A to a Git repository names `module-a`, like so:

```
module-a
`-- Module A
```

This is to maintain include path consistency. Option 1 was to migrate Module A into the root of a Git repository and then use `git mv` to recreate the folder, but this kind of loses log history. I know `git log --follow` fixes this, but we need to move a lot of repositories and a lot of UIs don't expose or support the `--follow` flag.

Option 2 was to checkout the root and use the `--ignore-paths` option, but this seems to pull in *all* of the Subversion history, which is a bit silly to have the entire history for just a small part of the repository.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish the above? One subdirectory of Subversion into a new Git repository, preserving the directory and the history for just the directory.

Answer (score 0):

### Caveat

What you want to do cuts slightly against the grain. A native solution would break modules A through D into separate repositories where each contains the contents beneath the `Module [ABCD]` directories. A fifth “super-repository” would tie them together using [`git submodule`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html) and have directories named `Module A` and friends.

### Answer

I assume you have good reasons for doing what you want to do.  Start with the first part of the import from Option 1, but rather than a final `git mv` commit, go back and rewrite your history using [`git filter-branch`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html), whose documentation contains an example invocation for pushing all files down one level in the directory tree.

Adapting to your situation, the adjustment for your first repository becomes

```
git filter-branch --index-filter \
        'git ls-files -s | sed "s-\t\"*-&Module A/-" |
                GIT_INDEX_FILE="$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" \
                        git update-index --index-info &&
         mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"' -- --all
```

Compare the rewritten branch to the backup under `refs/original/refs/heads`. To remove the backup, use (assuming your changes took place on the `master` branch)

```
git update-ref -d refs/original/refs/heads/master
```

Rinse and repeat for the other repositories.

### Walk-Through

Create a sample repository with placeholder data.

```
$ git init mymoda; cd mymoda
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/mymoda/.git/

$ touch foo.m; git add foo.m; git commit -m 'foo.m'
[master (root-commit) f321c95] foo.m
 0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 foo.m

$ mkdir bar; touch bar/bar.m; git add bar; git commit -m 'bar.m'
[master 608df91] bar.m
 0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 bar/bar.m

$ touch "`echo -e "dont\ttab\nme\\bro"`"; git add .; git commit -m weird
[master 524e78f] weird
 0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 "dont\ttab\nme\bro
```

Create a branch with content as well.

```
$ git checkout -b branch
Switched to a new branch 'branch'

$ touch "`echo -e "me\tneither"`"; git add .; git commit -m also\ weird
[branch 75b4c3c] also weird
 0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 "me\tneither"
```

See what we have so far. Note that [`git lola`](http://blog.kfish.org/2010/04/git-lola.html) is a non-standard but highly useful alias.

```
$ git lola --name-status
* 75b4c3c (HEAD, branch) also weird
| A     "me\tneither"
* 524e78f (master) weird
| A     "dont\ttab\nme\bro"
* 608df91 bar.m
| A     bar/bar.m
* f321c95 foo.m
  A     foo.m
```

Pretend that everything was actually beneath `Module A` all along.

```
$ git filter-branch --index-filter \
    'git ls-files -s | sed "s-\t\"*-&Module A/-" | \
      GIT_INDEX_FILE="$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" \
        git update-index --index-info && \
     mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"' -- --all
Rewrite 75b4c3cdf18f360ea29e7cf4bb6382b65b2ed536 (4/4)
Ref 'refs/heads/branch' was rewritten
Ref 'refs/heads/master' was rewritten
```

Now it looks like this.

```
$ git lola --name-status
* cf45854 (HEAD, branch) also weird
| A     "Module A/me\tneither"
* 58bc1ee (master) weird
| A     "Module A/dont\ttab\nme\bro"
* 4a1fe56 bar.m
| A     Module A/bar/bar.m
* e3e9eb2 foo.m
  A     Module A/foo.m
* 75b4c3c (refs/original/refs/heads/branch) also weird
| A     "me\tneither"
* 524e78f (refs/original/refs/heads/master) weird
| A     "dont\ttab\nme\bro"
* 608df91 bar.m
| A     bar/bar.m
* f321c95 foo.m
  A     foo.m
```

Review and remove the backups.

```
$ git update-ref -d refs/original/refs/heads/master
$ git update-ref -d refs/original/refs/heads/branch
```

The final result:

```
$ git lola --name-status
* cf45854 (HEAD, branch) also weird
| A     "Module A/me\tneither"
* 58bc1ee (master) weird
| A     "Module A/dont\ttab\nme\bro"
* 4a1fe56 bar.m
| A     Module A/bar/bar.m
* e3e9eb2 foo.m
  A     Module A/foo.m
```

### Low-level explanation

This involves a fair amount of munging. At its core is `git update-index` that adjusts path prefixes. The [“Using `--index-info`” section](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html#_using_index_info) of the documentation defines the formats `git update-index` accepts, with the third case being the one you are interested in.

> 3. *mode* `SP` *sha1* `SP` *stage* `TAB` *path*

Pushing a file down one level is a simple matter of appending a string prefix to the beginning of the path field fed to `git update-index`, and this is the purpose of the `sed` filter. In English, it reads

- substitute (`s`)
- using `-` as a delimiter around the search pattern and replacement
- search for ASCII `TAB` (`\t`) followed by zero or more double-quotes (`\"*`)
- replace with everything matched by the search (`&`), followed by the new parent directory, followed by slash (`Module A/`)

Note that the entire `sed` script must be quoted because it contains a space, namely in `Module A`, and this requires escaping the double-quote in the search pattern.

This does what you want because `TAB` introduces the path field of the output of `git ls-files -s` and marks the insertion point for the name of the new parent folder. The bit about zero or more double-quotes is to allow for weird paths that contain `TAB`, `LF`, or `\`, which will be escaped and quoted. In such cases, the `sed` script passes quoting unmodified.

After the new index is written successfully, the `mv` command swaps it into place to be stitched into your history with the `git filter-branch` mechanism.